# how to use sinon js with Express js unit testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, sinon, sinon-chai

Hi i want to do unit testing on my express js code i want to mock data so after searching multiple websites and blogs i found [this](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks) library but i am not clear how can i use this library for mocking or data.
My testing code is

```
var request = require('supertest');
var server = require('./app');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

var server = require('./app');

var should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('loading express', function () {

  it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/')
      .expect(200, done);
  });

  it('404 everything else', function testPath(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/foo/bar')
      .expect(404, done);
  });

  it('responds to /customers/getCustomerData', function testPath(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/customers/getCustomerData?id=0987654321')
      .end(function(err, res){
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a('object');
        res.body.status.should.equal("success");
        res.body.data.customerId.should.equal("0987654321");

        done();
      });
  });

});
```

Currently this code is fetching data from database but i want Unit testing using mock data. How can i achieve this?

**__EDIT__**

I want to test the code which is written inside Express js routes file. this routes i am calling inside **app.js** file like this

```
var customers = require('./routes/customers');
app.use('/customers', customers);
```

now the code which **customers route** file contain is

```
function getCustomerData(req, res, next) {
    var response = {};
    var cb = function (response) {
        res.send(response);
    }
    var modelObj = req.models.customer_master;
    var data = req.query;
    controllers.customers.get(modelObj, data, cb);
};
router.get('/getCustomerData', function (req, res, next) {
    getCustomerData(req, res, next);
});
```

**I want to test the response of "get" method using mock data**

Comment: You can mock the response with passthrough() like var response=new passthrough() but since you ae using supertest, you may check my answer that contains the test(s), files for your requirement. Looking at the date, you may already have found a solution, nevertheless, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You want to stub your controller middlewares i guess. As you didn't provide any server side code, i just asume some things:

```
app.get('/', rootController.get);
```

Now you want to stub this controller:

```
it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {
  const rootController = require('./path/to/your/controller');
  const rootControllerStub = sinon.stub(rootController, "get",
    function(req, res, next){
      res.status(200).json({stubbed: 'data'});
    });
  request(server)
    .get('/')
    .expect(200)
    .expect({stubbed: 'data'})
    .end(done);
});
```

Comment: Actually the code is written inside Express js routes file i want to test this code, but it does't have methods like "get". for more clarity i am editing my question. Thanks

Comment: well then mock only the thing you don't want to test, controllers.customers.get in your case

Comment: In the example you gave, isnt the test guaranteed to pass though?

Comment: @Embedded_Mugs in my example yes, OP wanted to test just the express routing which can be done with this. If a route is not present the test would fail. Same goes for some faulty middlewares in front of the controller.get fn

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to mock, you can use sinon express mocks [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-express-mock) or if you want to test the actual response data, JSON, use this [example](https://github.com/ravichandranjv/UnitTestingNodeJSRoute)

The express route, in the example, takes a parameter and returns a JSON

```
it('should respond with JSON data', function (done) {
  request(server)
    .get('/about/jv')
    .expect(200)
    .end(function (err, response) {
      assert.equal(response.header['content-type'], 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
      assert.deepEqual(response.body, {
        "data":{
        "username":"hellojv"}
      });
      done();
    });
```

but as mentioned above, if you want to use sinon then use the mock library. The example uses Mocha and supertest.

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly, if you write many test files, the stub may not work because of cache. I have to clear cache before initializing the stub and the server. The order is also important.

```js
// have to clear every module which belongs to the require chain
// APP require FOO ROUTE require FOO CONTROLLER require BAR LIB
const caches = [
    '../app',
    '../routes/foo',
    '../controller/foo',
];
caches.forEach(cache => {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(cache)];
});
// mock
const bar = require('../lib/bar');
sinon.stub(bar, 'bar').callsFake(async function() {
    return null;
});
app = require('../app');

// ... then the test ...
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857460/3000586)  helpful.